# Webflux: Add Subscriber Context Values from In-Stream Objects

Tags: spring-webflux

I have a Webflux application and I'm using the subscriber context to populate the MDC values so that they'll propagate downstream. I've implemented the classes from [this project](https://github.com/archie-swif/webflux-mdc/tree/master/src/main/java/com/example/webfluxmdc) to handle the MDC transfer between subscribers, setup a webfilter to add a request ID to incoming requests, and can see the request ID in the logs as part of the MDC.

```
public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, WebFilterChain chain) {
    return chain.filter(exchange)
            .contextWrite(Context.of("requestId", UUID.randomUUID().toString()));
}
```

Log output:

```
2021-09-30 17:15:29,963 [reactor-tcp-nio-2] INFO  c.p.l.s.RepoService:33 - MDC[requestId=ec0b68cf-ba4d-4c7f-afa4-f67fc97ebcbf] - Found user
```

The request needs to pull a user record from the database and I need to add the user's ID and email to the context once the data has been fetched, but I can't figure out how to add values to the context from objects within the stream.

So here's what I'm trying to do:

```
public Mono<Response> doProcessing(String userId, Object object) {
    return userRepo.findUserById(userId) //Returns UserEntity object
            .flatMap(userEntity -> service.doMoreProcessing(userEntity, object))
            .contextWrite(Context.of("userId", userId, "email", userEntity.getEmail()));
}
```

The problem is that I don't have access to the `userEntity` object when I call `contextWrite()`, so I can't add the user's email to the context using that call.

I've tried using `Mono.deferredContextual()`...

```
public Mono<Response> doProcessing(String userId, Object object) {
    return userRepo.findUserById(userId) //Returns UserEntity object
            .flatMap(userEntity -> Mono.deferContextual(ctx -> Mono.just(userEntity).contextWrite(Context.of(ctx).putAll(Context.of("userId", userId, "email", userEntity.getEmail()).readOnly()))))
            .flatMap(userEntity -> service.doMoreProcessing(userEntity, object));
}
```

...and `.transformDeferredContextual()`...

```
public Mono<Response> doProcessing(String userId, Object object) {
    return userRepo.findUserById(userId) //Returns UserEntity object
            .transformDeferredContextual((userEntityMono, contextView) -> userEntityMono.flatMap(userEntity -> Mono.just(userEntity).contextWrite(Context.of(contextView).putAll(Context.of("userId", userId, "email", userEntity.getEmail()).readOnly()))))
            .flatMap(userEntity -> service.doMoreProcessing(userEntity, object));
}
```

...but nothing has worked. How can I add data to the subscriber context from objects that are part of the process stream?

Comment: Out of curiosity what kind of info you want to pass down to the client. Can you use http header instead?

Comment: We don't really need to pass aything back to the client through the subscriber context. The goal here is to get the user email added to the MDC map for logging purposes. Since we're using the subscriber context to populate the MDC map, we need to be able to add the email string to the subscriber context.

Comment: I would usually prefer to use log for logging purpose rather than context but how about something like this.
`userRepo.findById(3).doOnNext(s -> Mono.just(s).contextWrite(context -> context.put("user", s.getId())));`

Comment: Well, I'm not really relying on the context call to perform any kind of actual logging. The context is just being used to populate the key/value pairs of the MDC map. The actual logging calls are handled outside of the context. Either way, I tried out your solution but the email info is still not getting added to the MDC map in the logs. I even tried adding a ```.subscribe()``` to the context call to ensure that the Mono was executing.

Answer (score 3):

The context can store a *mutable* state object like a `ConcurrentMap` or better yet a `@Data`-annotated class that could be accessed and modified on the chain (iff, you can guarantee you're not modifying the same field in the chain).

To get the data you need to obtain it from the signal using `doOnEach`, as `doOnNext` does not provide the signal value where you can `getContextView()`

You can try something like this

```
public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, WebFilterChain chain) {
        return chain.filter(exchange)
                .contextWrite(Context.of("your-key", new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Object>()));
}

public Mono<Response> doProcessing(String userId, Object object) {
    return userRepo.findUserById(userId)
            .doOnEach(signal -> {
                if (!signal.isOnNext()) return;
                Optional<Map<String, Object>> optional = signal.getContextView().getOrEmpty("your-key");
                optional.ifPresent(map -> {
                    map.put("userId", signal.get().getId());
                    map.put("email", signal.get().getEmail());
                });
            });
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).